# Design hierarchy with minimal code written

Tags: class, interface, abstract-class, hierarchy

I was once asked to design class/interface hierarchy to implement classes with minimal code redundancy

Let's say with have 3 classes that each 2 of them share the same code for some method (that is both class A and B has methodAB(), both class B and C has methodBC() etc.)

With such context I was asked is it better to create an abstract class that every class (A, B, C) extends or implement interfaces or maybe solve it differently?

Let's say that this problem can be extended to 4 classes (when each 3 of them has the same equal method) and so on. What is the best solution to this? Is there a way that code of each method will be written only once?

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use abstract classes you have the issue that(from your example) B will have to share methods with both class A and class B. So if you had a class AB which both A and B extend, you cannot have B extend a class BC again. As you said, you can do that with Interfaces, however you will be sharing prototypes of methods only and not implementation.

Having said that, C++, for example, is a language that allows multiple inheritance, which brings up other issues you need to be careful with(Diamond problem, etc). Additionally, in Java 8 you get [default methods](https://dzone.com/articles/interface-default-methods-java)(implementation) in interfaces.

In your question I think we are looking at [delegation pattern](http://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/patterns/delegation.html). Make sure to go through other design patterns - strategy is a bit similar too.

Comment: Yeah, the design patterns, thats probably what they expected from me... I'll start there then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case two questions need to be answered -

1. Are A,B,C replaceable by each other? if yes it means one method does
   not make sense in each class. This case arises rarely when we have
   to force few classes (Not similar to each other) to inherit from
   common base class (e.g. Composite pattern when we force leaf and
   composite to have same base class). If such artificial "IsA"
   relationship is required for some reason, we need to have common
   base class for A,B,C and provide empty implementation for one
   unusable method in each class (compromise). But I feel we need to
   have reason for such artificial relationship.
2. Are AB, BC and CA pairs repleable with each other (e.g. A and B are
   replaceable for one functionality, where as B and C are replaceable
   for another functionality)? If answer is Yes, then we need to
   capture each method in one interface and implement interfaces as
   required. A fictitious example can be A and B  are Runnable, B and C
   are Comparable and C and A are ActionListener.

But in general such a symptom needs to be rechecked at Object model level. Probably we may find we are violating Single responsibility principle or 'IsA' relationship. Such patches may get in to troble in future.

Comment: I wasn't very specific asking that question. The problem is that these common methods are identical when it comes to names. So every class has methodAB() but A and B has the same implementation of it, when C class has different (but still named methodAB()) and so on. And all of these classes should be "parallel" to each other which means in a simplest case they all should be extensions of base class - but the question is do we really need the base class or do we only need one or...?